# Polygons in C++

Tags: c++, boost

Suppose I have multiple polygons in the 2D space as the following image shows:

[image]

Each polygon is expressed with an a list of x-y coordinates. For example, Polygon A can be written as PolygonA: {(3,4), (7,8),..., (3,4)}. After all the polygons are generated, we want to perform some operations on them. For instance, we want to know all the polygons that are within a rectangle box. Or for a certain polygon, we want to know its neighboring polygons. Here is my question: how can I organize data structures so that the operations on polygons can become easier and efficient. The most straightforward way is to put all the polygons in a vector container. But operations on them become inefficient. Any ideas on proper data structures or libraries?

Comment: That depends on the type of operations. Do you have some example code to share`?

Comment: You can subdivide 2D space. Make a tree-like structure (like a binary space tree).

Answer (score 0):

Now this is just a tip!
I would do it a different way. It's (as you already said) *way* too unperformant to operate with a whole polygon. An often used *help* is to seperate a polygon into smaller (way easier to calculate) shapes.

Let's say you have a polygon.[image]

again, operating with every single coordinate.. No way.
Let's say you have an algorithm that returns a number of shapes depending on a "intensity factor". It could look like this.

```
std::vector<Shape> fill_with_shapes(const Polygon &a, float intensity); //example
```

and the greater the intensity gets, the more detail.
[image]

and (if you want) even more.[image]

Calculation with rectangles and triangles is way more simple than with a whole polygon. Now, I don't have the code for such a 'fill_with_shapes' function, again, this answer is more an advice *before* you do any operations.. I hope the idea helps!

Comment: additionally I would save at least one AABB (axis-aligned bounding box) that contains the whole polygon which makes for a quick and cheap test to dismiss most polygons (sorting them all along an axis can additionally help for a quick lookup)

Answer (score 0):

I consider to use r-tree from boost::geometry library, and it seems a good solution. I post the codes as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/extensions/index/rtree/rtree.hpp>
#include <vector>


#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/extensions/index/rtree/rtree.hpp>

#include <random>

#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    namespace bg = boost::geometry;
    namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

    typedef bg::model::point<float,2,bg::cs::cartesian> point;
    typedef bg::model::box<point> box;

    typedef bgi::rtree<box,unsigned > rtreeType;

    rtreeType rtree(6,3);

    for(unsigned i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        box b(point(i+0.1f,i+0.1f),point(i+0.5f,i+0.5f));
        rtree.insert(b,i);
    }

    box query_box(point(0,0),point(5,5));

    rtree.print();

    std::cout<<"number of elements: ";
    std::cout<<rtree.elements()<<std::endl;


    // application 1: search for boxes that are within query_box
    std::deque<unsigned> &boxValue=rtree.find(query_box);





    return 0;
}
```